# Strong Parameters in Rails - Require clause is being disregarded

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, routes, strong-parameters

In short, a POST request is being made to `/games`.

Even though the strong params requirement looks like this:

```
def game_params
  params.require(:game).permit(:name)
end
```

A json request without a `game` object, just a `name` field actually goes through.

```
{
    "name": "Game of Life"
}
```

Even more oddly, the rails logger actually makes a game object! The log looks like

```
Parameters: { "name" => "Game of life", "game" => {"name" => "Game of life"}}
```

implying that a game object is being created. If the sole parameter passes is *not* `name`, Rails will correctly throw a 400.

All the docs I've read suggest that the `game` object in the JSON is an absolute must, but it appears to be ignored here.

Advice?

Comment: It is not clear how did you send your JSON data to Rails server. Can you provide the whole request you made url, method, data, headers

Comment: Can you provide your controller method as well? Are you actually calling `game_params`, or do you have something like `Game.create(name: params[:name])` in your controller?

Comment: @jdno Actually calling game params; very odd behavior

Comment: Are you sure you are not sending in `game: { name: "Game of life" }` with your request? The most logical explanation to me is that you are accidentally including the game in your request, which explains both the log message and why you are not getting an error. Because you are right, without it there should be an error.

Comment: @jdno absolutely 100% certain. I've done a bunch of Rails projects before, and I've never seen anything like this.

Comment: @jdno See answer! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, an update for anyone who needed to know this.

The answer, after a bunch of digging, is -

If your require clause has an object name that matches your controller name, Rails is going to make that object optional. You can turn off this behavior in your initializers.

Source: https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.1/classes/ActionController/ParamsWrapper.html

Comment: Good find. I have never used parameter wrapping, and was not aware that it even existed. Thanks for posting the solution, this might come in handy in the future.